# How does this non-isolated circuit create 12VDC from mains supply?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I took apart a PIR sensor, and inside it has a circuit similar to this (it uses the same chip):

[image]

I don't quite understand how this rectifies and creates 12VDC. My understanding so far is the (68 + jw0.68) is the current limiter, and the 12V zener is used as a reference voltage.

However, I'm having understanding:

1. The ground point (i.e. the wire between the two zener diodes) and polarities. On the positive cycle, the top zener will be ~12V, and the bottom will be ~-0.7V, referred to the ground. In the negative cycle, the opposite will occur. So how does this rectify the voltage?
2. How does the 470uF capacitor act as a smoothing capacitor?

I simulated the circuit like so:

[image]

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the top oscillates between -0.7mV and 12V. Why is this node connected to anything if it isn't 12V?
I'm not sure why it becomes a square wave, but that might be another question.

I'm not sure if I connected the load in the correct place. It's only drawing 7.5mA and cannot regulate the voltage at all..

Comment: During one half-cycle one of the zener diodes is acting as a zener and has 12V across it the other zener is acting as a forward biased diode.  During the other half cycle this is also true but the roles are reversed. The 68 ohm resistor and 330nF capacitor limit the current. Also note you should connect "Top" to the load too as with your circuit you are only using one half-cycle.

Comment: @WarrenHill Are you saying to connect the load between top and the bottom node where load currently is? If so, how does the 470uF capacitor smooth the voltage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The Zeners don't rectify the voltage at all- they just limit it. The 1N4002s rectify the voltage. If you look at the voltages from the standpoint of the "ground", there are two opposite phase square-ish waves that go to +12 alternately. The two rectifiers steer the higher one to the 470uF capacitor.
2. The 470uF capacitor charges when the voltage on the other side of either of the 1N4002s is higher, and discharges when it drops.

It's very much like the standard 2-diode full-wave rectifier circuit with a center-tapped transformer, except the waveforms are more squared so the rectifiers don't have to work as hard.

[image]

Here is what the circuit startup looks like:

[image]

And after it's started up, the waveforms at the diodes look like this:
[image]

Comment: Is there an easy explanation for why the waveform becomes more squared, or does that warrant another question?

Comment: Easy explanation- for less than 12V or so the voltage just follows the mains waveform - increasing very steeply. Once it hits about 12V the diodes conduct and charge the filter capacitor and any extra current gets shunted away by the Zener diodes.

Answer (score 7):

Your simulation circuit is not connected properly. Go back and look at the original circuit and note that the cathodes of both of the 1N4002's are connected together. This common connection forms the +DC rail of the "off the mains" power supply.

[image]

Note also that the zener diodes are not working so much as a reference but as a +12V clamp to limit how high the +DC rail can rise in voltage. This in fact is what "regulates" the DC voltage (If you can in fact call it regulation when in fact all it does is "limit" the voltage. With the original circuit as shown the load on the +DC rail needs to be kept under about 20mA to allow the rail to get up to 12VDC level clamped by the zener diodes. A greater load results in a lower DC voltage due to the current limiting through the 0.68uF capacitor and the 68 ohm resistor. Also interesting is that with the 470uF filter capacitor it takes almost 1 second to get up to the 12V level with a 24mA load.